# How to assign a css class or id to smileys?

Tags: css, ckeditor

I'm setting up CKEditor in Drupal 7 and what I need is assign an additional CSS class (or ID, no matter) to smileys to style them differently from other images. What is the best way to do it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/*
 Copyright (c) 2003-2015, CKSource - Frederico Knabben. All rights reserved.
 For licensing, see LICENSE.md or http://ckeditor.com/license
*/
CKEDITOR.dialog.add("smiley", function (f) {
    for (var e = f.config, a = f.lang.smiley, h = e.smiley_images, g = e.smiley_columns || 8, k, m = function (l) { var c = l.data.getTarget(), b = c.getName(); if ("a" == b) c = c.getChild(0); else if ("img" != b) return; var b = c.getAttribute("cke_src"), a = c.getAttribute("title"), c = f.document.createElement("img", { attributes: { src: b, "data-cke-saved-src": b, title: a, alt: a, width: c.$.width, height: c.$.height, "class": "smiley" } }); f.insertElement(c); k.hide(); l.data.preventDefault() }, q = CKEDITOR.tools.addFunction(function (a, c) {
    a =
    new CKEDITOR.dom.event(a); c = new CKEDITOR.dom.element(c); var b; b = a.getKeystroke(); var d = "rtl" == f.lang.dir; switch (b) {
    case 38: if (b = c.getParent().getParent().getPrevious()) b = b.getChild([c.getParent().getIndex(), 0]), b.focus(); a.preventDefault(); break; case 40: (b = c.getParent().getParent().getNext()) && (b = b.getChild([c.getParent().getIndex(), 0])) && b.focus(); a.preventDefault(); break; case 32: m({ data: a }); a.preventDefault(); break; case d ? 37 : 39: if (b = c.getParent().getNext()) b = b.getChild(0), b.focus(), a.preventDefault(!0);
    else if (b = c.getParent().getParent().getNext()) (b = b.getChild([0, 0])) && b.focus(), a.preventDefault(!0); break; case d ? 39 : 37: if (b = c.getParent().getPrevious()) b = b.getChild(0), b.focus(), a.preventDefault(!0); else if (b = c.getParent().getParent().getPrevious()) b = b.getLast().getChild(0), b.focus(), a.preventDefault(!0)
    }
    }), d = CKEDITOR.tools.getNextId() + "_smiley_emtions_label", d = ['\x3cdiv\x3e\x3cspan id\x3d"' + d + '" class\x3d"cke_voice_label"\x3e' + a.options + "\x3c/span\x3e", '\x3ctable role\x3d"listbox" aria-labelledby\x3d"' +
    d + '" style\x3d"width:100%;height:100%;border-collapse:separate;" cellspacing\x3d"2" cellpadding\x3d"2"', CKEDITOR.env.ie && CKEDITOR.env.quirks ? ' style\x3d"position:absolute;"' : "", "\x3e\x3ctbody\x3e"], n = h.length, a = 0; a < n; a++) {
        0 === a % g && d.push('\x3ctr role\x3d"presentation"\x3e'); var p = "cke_smile_label_" + a + "_" + CKEDITOR.tools.getNextNumber(); d.push('\x3ctd class\x3d"cke_dark_background cke_centered" style\x3d"vertical-align: middle;" role\x3d"presentation"\x3e\x3ca href\x3d"javascript:void(0)" role\x3d"option"',
        ' aria-posinset\x3d"' + (a + 1) + '"', ' aria-setsize\x3d"' + n + '"', ' aria-labelledby\x3d"' + p + '"', ' class\x3d"cke_smile cke_hand" tabindex\x3d"-1" onkeydown\x3d"CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction( ', q, ', event, this );"\x3e', '\x3cimg class\x3d"cke_hand" title\x3d"', e.smiley_descriptions[a], '" cke_src\x3d"', CKEDITOR.tools.htmlEncode(e.smiley_path + h[a]), '" alt\x3d"', e.smiley_descriptions[a], '"', ' src\x3d"', CKEDITOR.tools.htmlEncode(e.smiley_path + h[a]), '"', CKEDITOR.env.ie ? " onload\x3d\"this.setAttribute('width', 2); this.removeAttribute('width');\" " :
        "", '\x3e\x3cspan id\x3d"' + p + '" class\x3d"cke_voice_label"\x3e' + e.smiley_descriptions[a] + "\x3c/span\x3e\x3c/a\x3e", "\x3c/td\x3e"); a % g == g - 1 && d.push("\x3c/tr\x3e")
    } if (a < g - 1) { for (; a < g - 1; a++) d.push("\x3ctd\x3e\x3c/td\x3e"); d.push("\x3c/tr\x3e") } d.push("\x3c/tbody\x3e\x3c/table\x3e\x3c/div\x3e"); e = { type: "html", id: "smileySelector", html: d.join(""), onLoad: function (a) { k = a.sender }, focus: function () { var a = this; setTimeout(function () { a.getElement().getElementsByTag("a").getItem(0).focus() }, 0) }, onClick: m, style: "width: 100%; border-collapse: separate;" };
    return { title: f.lang.smiley.title, minWidth: 270, minHeight: 120, contents: [{ id: "tab1", label: "", title: "", expand: !0, padding: 0, elements: [e] }], buttons: [CKEDITOR.dialog.cancelButton] }
});
```

Change your smiley.js with this.
This introduce class **smiley** in CKEditor smile