# Add class or inline style to CkEditor Smiley when inserted

Tags: ckeditor

I'm using Ck Editor in a program that builds email templates. Every email template has it's own styles that overwrites text inside the content blocks.

So currently when I add a smiley in the text block with Ck Editor, the template styles adds float left and display block to images inside the text block.

Which means that all smileys are floated to the left.

Is there a way that I can add inline styles to the actual smiley image that's inserted so that it looks like this:

```
<img alt="cool" height="23" src="/vendors/ckeditor/plugins/smiley/images/shades_smile.png" title="cool" width="23" style="float: none; display: inline-block;">
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: See this similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29014728/how-to-assign-a-css-class-or-id-to-smileys

Answer (score 0):

You can try to check when inserting an element if it the src attribute contains a string like "smiley" for example and then add a class or inline style to the element:

```js
CKEDITOR.replace('editor1', {
  on: {
    insertElement: function(e) {
      if (e.data.getName() !== 'img') return;
      if (e.data.getAttribute('src').indexOf('smiley') > -1) {
        e.data.addClass('smiley-class');
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.7.3/full-all/ckeditor.js"></script>
<textarea name="editor1"></textarea>
```